# Return to page after contact form submit and produce dialog box

Tags: php, phpmailer, contact-form

I have a contact form which on submit, should return to the contact form page and produce a dialog box with "Message sent". I'm not worrying about errors or unsuccessful submissions at this time.

This is where my form submits to:

```
form id="formLeft" action="Assets/php/contactForm.php" method="post">
```

This is what I am currently using in the contactForm.php file:

```
<?php 

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formContent="From: " . $name . "<br>Email: " . $email . "<br>Company: " . $company . "<br>Message: " . $message;
$mailHeader = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$mailHeader .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$mailheader .= "From:x@x \r\n";
mail("x@x","Contact Form Message",$formContent, $mailHeader);
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("Message successfully sent.")';
echo '</script>';
header("Location: http://mywebsite.co.uk/contact.html");
exit;
?>
```

Without the echo's, the code successfully redirects to the contact page, but with the echo lines the alert works but then a page with the following error is shown:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent
```

Any ideas on how I can return to the contact form and produce a success alert box will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is because you first printing script message and then sending headers.

send a query string to contact form where you can get that query string and show the message there. something like `header("Location: http://mywebsite.co.uk/contact.html?success=1");`

get query string in success in contact page and then show the alert

Comment: @MurtazaBhurgri but if put the echo after the header the alert does not appear.

Comment: Don't echo alert in this page copy this code and paste this in contact page. Pass variable in redirection contact.html?success=1 so when you get query string in contact.html then it means email is sent and action is successful. If you google pass query string in php header you will get my point.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to header injection attack. Use an email library, like PHPMailer that you tagged this question with.